# How do i pass AWS credentials using a process variable containing an AWS service endpoint id

Tags: amazon-web-services, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I want to use two variables, $(Aws.Endpoint) and $(Aws.Region), in my AWS-related release tasks, and provide values for those as process variables.
Aws.Endpoint is the id of an aws service endpoint in VSTS. When i do this, i get

```
Endpoint auth data not present: ...
```

Has anyone who ran into this seemingly trivial issue found a solution? Otherwise i need to define the aws endpoint directly in the task, which feels wrong, because i eventually want the release tasks to be part of a task group, shared by all the environment making up the pipeline (dev, stage, prod).

Note: i see there is no stackoverflow tag for AWS Tools for Visual Studio Team Services, and i don't have the reputation to create a new tag. If someone with enough reputation could create something like `aws-tools-for-vsts` ([homepage](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vsts/latest/userguide/welcome.html)), that would be grand.

Answer (score 0):

No, you can’t do it for the tasks in AWS tools for Microsoft Visual Studio Team Services extension. You can custom build/release task to meet your requirement through VSTS extension.

If you want to get AWS endpoint in your custom build/release task, you can get the endpoint through [Get-VstsEndpoint](https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-task-lib/blob/master/powershell/Docs/FullHelp/Get-VstsEndpoint.md) or [task.getEndpointAuthorization](https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-task-lib/blob/master/node/docs/vsts-task-lib.md#taskEndpointAuthorization) with the GUID of service (can get in build/release log: `##[debug]awsCredentials=9a3009d2-35f3-4954-a8fa-34c3313c34f6`)

For example:

```
$awsEndpoint = Get-VstsEndpoint -Name [GUID of service] -Require
Write-Host $awsEndpoint
foreach($p in $awsEndpoint.Auth.Parameters){
Write-Host $p
}
```